# Sharing Facebook access tokens between different devices of same user

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-sdk-4.0

Users can log in to our app from different devices. We want to transfer users' access tokens to all devices they log in from for them not to go through Facebook login steps again in each device they use.

In one of Facebook's developer documentation pages (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/portability), it's said that;

> Access tokens are portable. This means that once you obtain a token,
>   you can generally use it from any machine - server, client, or
>   otherwise.

and this document also details how to set a current access token to be used by the Facebook SDK.

But in another page (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/expiration-and-extension), it's said that

> You should, in general, not use the same long-lived tokens on more
>   than one web client (i.e. if the person logs in from more than one
>   computer.) Instead you should use the long-lived tokens on your server
>   to generate a code and then use that to get a long-lived token on the
>   client.

So, can we share the access token acquired on one of a user's devices to other devices of this same user or not?

Comment: The client-side SDKs usually see to it that you automatically get a fresh short-lived token whenever the user is using the app ... so there should be no need to send tokens from the server to any client devices in the first place for most use cases.

Comment: Users can log in to our app from different devices. We want to transfer users' access tokens to all devices they log in from for them not to go through Facebook login steps again in each device they use.