# Is it possible to log in to Facebook from another device and use the access on a primary device

Tags: unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, facebook-access-token, android-facebook, facebook-unity-sdk

I want my users to be able to log in to Facebook from a tablet and use their access in a Unity project installed on a virtual reality headset (Oculus Go).

My goal is to avoid people to log in to Facebook inside virtual reality. The scenario is:

1. Log In to Facebook with an Android App on a tablet
2. Send the Facebook AccessToken to the virtual headset
3. Put the virtual headset + **Automatically Log In with AccessToken (How?)**
4. Share a link on your wall within virtual reality

I can get an AccessToken when logged on tablet but there's no function in the Unity Facebook SDK where I can use this token to automatically log the users in virtual reality.

As mentionned in this question: [Sharing Facebook access tokens between different devices of same user?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47387276/sharing-facebook-access-tokens-between-different-devices-of-same-user)

> Access tokens are portable. This means that once you obtain a token, you can generally use it from any machine - server, client, or otherwise.

If the tokens are portable, how can I use it to log in my user on another device?

Comment: number 4 is not possible, you cannot post on the user wall anymore with the api.

Comment: @luschn Since August 1st, 2018, you still can but you need to be a Facebook approved partners. (Source: Graph-api ChangeLog of April 2018)

Comment: well, that usually means that you can´t :) - or are you a FB partner?

Comment: anyway, you don´t "login" with a token, you just use it to get/post data. and user tokens are not valid forever, so you would need to refresh it once in a while - on your device.